# jtextarea scrolling

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtextarea

I'm using jtextarea and it is filled dynamically during execution of my application(like logs).I want remove autoscrolling of vertical scrollbar, I mean text is adding in field and caret position isn't changing(it changes only if I dragged it manually). How can I do this? I tried `scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setAutoscrolls(false)`
but this didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, the text area doesn't scroll; you must have something in your code to make it happen.

The usual approach is to set the caret at the end of the document (plus `caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);` when you're on Java 5; see [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/))

To stop the scrolling, you must find the code in your app and turn it off.

`setAutoscrolls()` has no effect in this case because it's only used when you drag select text and the mouse gets outside of the component plus the purpose of this property is something else (if `true`, synthetic mouse events will be generated as long as the mouse is outside the component).

Comment: in DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE mode caret.getDot() returns 0.How can I find current caret position to compare it with myTextArea.getDocument().getLength() and perform necessary actions?

Comment: By calling `myTextArea.getCaretPosition()`. Do you want to scroll automatically or do you want to **avoid** scrolling? Your question isn't really clear...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use  something like this:

```
myTextArea.setCaretPosition(myTextArea.getDocument().getLength() - 1);
```

Comment: Right idea, but don't use getText(). A new string has to be build from all the text in the Document. Instead just use `getDocument().getLength()`.

Comment: @camickr: Thanks! I didn't know about how this works internally before.